# Can I save my preferences in Android that I can edit in the App Manager

Tags: android, kotlin

Generally a set of preferences becomes writtenaway into a file but I'd like to edit in the android App Manager how do I implement this in Kotlin?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is "the android App Manager"?

Comment: I'd like my preferences edit not programatically but in the Android App Manager where must I save my preference for this purpus.

Comment: You open on your Android "Adjust" there "Apps"